# having trouble declaring a fixed size byte array constant

Tags: solidity, arrays, data-types

I was able to declare this constant as a bytes object, but am trying to compress it for efficiency, and I'm getting this error message:

```
Only constants of value type and byte array type are implemented.
```

I don't understand, is this not a byte array? why is this error happening? is there a way to convert such a number to a fixed size byte array?

```
bytes32[8] public constant N = [bytes32(hex'c7970ceedcc3b0754490201a7aa613cd73911081c790f5f1a8726f463550bb5b'), 
bytes32(hex'7ff0db8e1ea1189ec72f93d1650011bd721aeeacc2acde32a04107f0648c2813'), 
bytes32(hex'a31f5b0b7765ff8b44b4b6ffc93384b646eb09c7cf5e8592d40ea33c80039f35'), 
bytes32(hex'b4f14a04b51f7bfd781be4d1673164ba8eb991c2c4d730bbbe35f592bdef524a'), 
bytes32(hex'f7e8daefd26c66fc02c479af89d64d373f442709439de66ceb955f3ea37d5159'), 
bytes32(hex'f6135809f85334b5cb1813addc80cd05609f10ac6a95ad65872c909525bdad32'), 
bytes32(hex'bc729592642920f24c61dc5b3c3b7923e56b16a4d9d373d8721f24a3fc0f1b31'),
bytes32(hex'31f55615172866bccc30f95054c824e733a5eb6817f7bc16399d48c6361cc7e5')];
```

Answer (score 0):

What "byte array type" means is the `bytes` type in Solidity. You cannot use any other array type for constant declarations as the time of writing.

The way you would declare a constant of the type `bytes` is as follows:

```
bytes public constant BYTE_ARRAY = hex'abcd';
```

For your example above, the correct way to do it would be as follows:

```
bytes public constant N = abi.encodePacked([
        bytes32(hex'c7970ceedcc3b0754490201a7aa613cd73911081c790f5f1a8726f463550bb5b'), 
        bytes32(hex'7ff0db8e1ea1189ec72f93d1650011bd721aeeacc2acde32a04107f0648c2813'), 
        bytes32(hex'a31f5b0b7765ff8b44b4b6ffc93384b646eb09c7cf5e8592d40ea33c80039f35'), 
        bytes32(hex'b4f14a04b51f7bfd781be4d1673164ba8eb991c2c4d730bbbe35f592bdef524a'), 
        bytes32(hex'f7e8daefd26c66fc02c479af89d64d373f442709439de66ceb955f3ea37d5159'), 
        bytes32(hex'f6135809f85334b5cb1813addc80cd05609f10ac6a95ad65872c909525bdad32'), 
        bytes32(hex'bc729592642920f24c61dc5b3c3b7923e56b16a4d9d373d8721f24a3fc0f1b31'),
        bytes32(hex'31f55615172866bccc30f95054c824e733a5eb6817f7bc16399d48c6361cc7e5')
]);
```